# git : clone doesn't bring in all the files?

Tags: git

I just created directory called `website`. This has a couple of images, index.html page etc. I ran : `git --bare init --shared=0777`

Now, it successfully created an empty shared repo.

I now try to clone this project by going into `/developers/developer1` on my server and running `git clone /live/website`. I get the following message:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /developer/developer1/website/.git/
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
```

I'm running UNIX. When I do a `ls`, all I see is the .git folder and none of the images/ index.html page have been cloned here. I tried to do:

```
git pull /live/website origin
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref origin
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

git pull /live/website master
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I know I need to be doing `origin` because when I do a `git remote -v`, here's what I get:

```
origin  /live/website  (fetch)
origin  /live/website (push)
```

So in a nutshell, here's what I need help doing:

1. Figure out how to clone all my files from /live/website to /developer1
2. Be able to make changes to the files locally on developer1 and push those changes back.

However, since I can't seem to get the files in the first place, I can't really proceed! The major intention is to allow a lot of developers to simultaneously work on the files and push their changes to the main `/live/website` directory, once they are done.

Comment: With your `git pull /live/website origin` and `git pull /live/website master` commands, I think what you mean is `git pull origin master`. This is equivalent to `git pull /live/website master` since `origin` maps to `/live/website`, but the `git pull origin master` is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for th tip Cameron. However, earlier I thought origin was a branch, that is why I was trying it. I now understand its just a mapping to /live/website ... (or the source from where it has been cloned).

Answer (score 4):

You have to do some steps to get files into your repo. Assume you have a server where the bare repo is stored and some workstations where the actual work is done.

1. Initialize the bare repo on your *server* like you wrote:
   `git --bare init --shared=0777`
2. Checkout this directory to your *workstation1*:
   `git clone git://server/repo.git`
3. Drop some files into this freshly cloned repo and add them to the track. To add all of them, do a `git add .`
4. Commit the added files to the local repository:
   `git commit -m 'initial commit'`
   Now, the changes (adding files) were stored in the local repository.
5. Finally, push back the files (assuming you work on branch *master*) to the server (known as *origin*):
   `git push origin master`
6. Now, do some more local changes and commit them to the local repo as in step 4. When you type `git status` now, it should give you a message like 
   `Your branch is ahead of origin/whatever by 1 commit`
7. To bring the changes back to the central repo, you can simply type `git push` since you set up the tracking of the branch in step 5.

Now, if you do a `git clone git://server/repo.git` from another machine (e.g. *workstation2*), you will get the files you just checked in...

That's the general git workflow:

- Get the files from the server (initial: `clone`, consecutive `pull`)
- Do some changes and store them in the local repo (`git commit`)
- When the time has come, push back the local commits to the bare repo (`git push`)

To get a more detailed explanation, see the section *Private Small Team* in the online version of the [progit book](http://progit.org/book/ch5-2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Does it matter though that I'm using master and push doesn't work directly? Also, I do see the files when I check them out. However, I don't see the files present in the --bare repo itself. Is there anyway I can? The reason being I want to use this as my live folder that has the latest website version and developers can basically checkout the version and make changes locally.

Comment: A `bare` repo does not have a working copy, so it won't show the files. I suspect in your case you don't want the live version to be bare. You might want to consider having a post-receive or post-update hook that copies commits to the live site rather than pushing directly it.

Comment: @g1t: thanks for pointing out that the initial sequence of my answer didn't work. Reworked (and actually tested) the steps described. Now, it should work fine.

Comment: Cam, your right. I shouldn't be going with `bare`. I was reading a few tutorials online and one of them mentioned pushing/pulling from a non-bare repo was asking for trouble. I do want to be able to see the latest files, so I guess I need to take this risk. However, can I restrict the branches in this live repo? I merely want people to be able to `pull/push` from this folder and do the development on their local folders.I'm going to look at how to undo a `git push` as well. eckes, thanks again! I just saw the link in your post, I'm going to try and see what I can get out of it ..

Answer (score -2):

when you create a repository with `git init` it starts as an empty repository. you have to add files (`git add -- file1 file2 other files`) first and then create a commit (`git commit -m'initial commit'`).

you should then be able to clone said repository using `git clone` and fetch/pull from it

Comment: I've created my repository as a --bare. As I understand it, this means that I don't have a working branch like master. I did try your suggestion on my `/live/website` directory and expectedly, here's the error I get:  **git add . fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree**

Comment: a --bare repository is as empty as a normal repository when created. you have to push to it before you can clone it

Comment: Hmm, so your saying that having the files in the directory and then initializing it as a bare, makes no difference? I need to create it and then `git push <a_branch>` into it for it to keep track of all the files?

Comment: a bere repository does not know where it is located and that you want the files to automagically be versioned. how is that supposed to work?

Comment: you have to create a commit containing the files first (have you read my answer?) and then push to /live/website2 (`git push /live/website2 master`). to be able to use origin you need to add a remote first (`git remote add origin /live/website2`). also you seem to be confusing origin as a branch?

Comment: @g1t: Here is an outline: `cd /path/to/content; git init; git add .; git commit; cd /bare/path; git init --bare content.git; cd /path/to/content; git push /bare/path/content.git`. If you're still having trouble you might want to go read a tutorial.

Comment: Knitt, I tried that just before seeing your reply. I was indeed confusing origin as a branch. I was able to successfully push when using master. `Counting objects: 5, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads. Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done. Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 662 bytes, done. Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done. To /live/website2`. However, when I browse to the directory /live/website2, I don't see my files and I merely see the files that git places there: branches  `config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs`

Comment: you don't see the files, because you have created a `--bare` repository. it's a repository without a working tree, IOW without files