# Using Git on OS X - uploading not happening?

Tags: git, macos, upload

Mac 10.6 – I am getting all the right signals in my command line when I save out to Git... but nothing appears in my Git webspace folder?

When I type in `which git` it returns `/usr/local/git/bin/git` – is this correct as am new to all this.

I did set up the `.gitconfig` file and placed it in my Home folder – should it be in the project root directory maybe?

Comment: cut-n-paste of input and output can help immensely :) And what is "my Git webspace folder"?

Comment: @sarnold - I meant to say GitHub

Answer (score 1):

From what you're writing, Git seems to work perfectly.

Assume you have a git repo in your local directory, say `~/src/project_dir`. Then this directory will have a child dir called `.git`. This is the repository. Whenever you do a `commit`, changes get committed to this repository.

What do you mean with *Git webspace folder*? Is this a remote repository (e.g. at github) that you want to push the changes to? In that case, you have to setup the remote repository first as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391675/git-clone-doesnt-bring-in-all-the-files/4391998#4391998).

Answer (score 0):

When you commit changes to a git repository, it isn't stored in a central system repository. It sounds like you're expecting commits made in `/src/website/` to be committed to `/usr/local/git/`, when they would instead be stored in the repository at `/src/website/.git` by default.

Comment: Yes, that may be the case alright. How do I set Git up to save my project files directly up into Github (I have an account set up) instead of onto my local machine somewhere? I can't even find them on my local machine - so no idea where they are going to!

Comment: @user372237: what do you mean with "I can't even find them on my local machine"? They are in your working directory. That IS the repository! You can't directly push them to Github. You have 2 repos: a local one and the remote one at Github. You commit to the local one and sometimes (or after each commit), you push the changes to the remote repo at Github!

Comment: Hi - there's nothing in the root file of my project that suggests its a Git repo/backup of my files?

<p> iMac:user$ git commit -a -m 'Validation!'          
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

iMac:user$ which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
</p>

Comment: @user372237: please see my answer. Discuss there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676755/using-git-on-os-x-uploading-not-happening/4677567#4677567. And use `@username` in comments in order to notify `username`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, am going back to copy+paste as this is too confusing!